# Environment.TickCount VS StopWatch

Tags: c#, .net, stopwatch, system.diagnostics

What are the advantages of using a [StopWatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead using [Environment.TickCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.environment.tickcount%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

I usually get the elapsed time using the following mechanism:

```
int ini = Environment.TickCount
// perform some operations
int elapsedMilliseconds = Environment.TickCount - ini;
```

But some SO experts recommended using an StopWatch:

```
StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();
sw.Start();
// perform some operations
sw.Stop();
int elapsedMilliseconds = sw.EllpasedMillseconds;
```

Is just a OOP thing, or maybe I'm measuring the elapsed time in a wrong way?